# Entity Framework 6 Select Anonymous Type Load Child Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

The entity "SampleBookMasters" has a property `public virtual ICollection<SampleBookBOMDetail> BOMDetails { get; set; }`.

Is it possible to load all BomDetails simultaneously when I call `profiles.ToList()` ?

I need to convert the result to JSON but it is very slow if `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` .

After I did some Google, I found that the converting process will trigger lazy loading to load the BOMDetails.

If I have 5k of SampleBookMaster, I guess it will trigger 5k times to load the BomDetails.

So I try to disable lazy loading.

But the result is not what I'm excepted, after I called `profiles.ToList()`, the BomDetails is always null.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var profiles = from q in db.SampleBookMasters

                join i in db.ItemMasters on q.Material equals i.Material into dept
                join v in db.VendorMasters on q.Vendor_code equals v.Vendor
                from Item in dept.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    SampleBookMaster = q, //Here!
                    VendorMasters = v,
                    Old_material_no = Item.Old_material_no,
                    Sample_book_disable = q.Sample_book_disable,
                    Create_account = q.Create_account
                               
                };

var results = profiles.ToList();
```

Comment: `db.SampleBookMasters.Include(bom => bom.BOMDetails).Select(bom => new { ... }).ToList()`?